# Firebase Crashing iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I am implementing Firebase in my iOS app. I installed it via cocoapods. I also added the .plist file. Everything is linked to a project.

When I configure the app in the delegate file using `FirebaseApp.configure()` it crashes. In the debug menu it says `ibc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

Things I have tried:

Made sure I imported Firebase in the delegate

Made sure the .plist file is linked to target

Checked stack overflow

Checked Apple Dev Forums

Redone everything in a new Xcode project

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted some code to show us how you're implementing Firebase in your project. Also what do you mean you "imported Firebase in the delegate"? What delegate? Do you mean you imported the Firebase framework in the `AppDelegate`? Another thing to make sure of is that you're using your `.xcworkspace` workspace file and not the project file once you've used `cocoapods` to manage your dependencies.

Comment: @Pierce I am using the .xcworkspace and also by delegate I mean app delegate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After implementing the Firebase...

In the AppDelegate, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions func you need to add:

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true  // If you use persistent data in your app.
```

The first is to start teh Firebase and the secont to persistence data.
Note: Dont forget to import Firebase in the AppDelegate Controller and make sure install the Firebase key from google "GoobleService-Info.plist".

Comment: This is not correct, you don't need to add *Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true*. That's only needed if you are using offline persistence and is not a requirement. The rest of the answer is ok.

Comment: @Maximo What is the firebase key?

Comment: @Nol4635 Open your browser, go to Firebase App console > Project Overview - Settings(The small round icon) > Project Settings >  Download the latest config file -> "GoobleService-Info.plist"  -  After download, copy this file to your project folder with your Info.plist.

Comment: @MaximoLucosi I have done this